# Adding keywords to google shopping feed with the product_type attribute

Tags: seo, ecommerce, google-ads

Most of our products are of Irish origin, which is important for our customers who often use the keywords Irish or Ireland in their searches.

Many of our products do not have Ireland or Irish in their title/name so I was wondering if I could add a google attribute to add in these keywords.

You can add as many `product_type` attributes to your feed as you want.

> This attribute also indicates the category of the product being
>   submitted, but you can provide your own classification. Unlike the
>   'Google product category', you can include more than one 'product
>   type' attribute value if products apply to more than one category.
>   https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/188494#product_type

Could we then use this as a kind of keyword for our products, for instance. . .

```
<g:product_type><![CDATA[Irish]]></g:product_type>
<g:product_type><![CDATA[Ireland]]></g:product_type>
```